# jquery animate scrollTop and scrollLeft not working on ipad simultaneously

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, scrolltop

I have the following snippet of code that animates my page to a specific point on my frontpage. This is working perfectly on all browsers and on android tablets.

```
if($("body").hasClass("mobile")){
   $scrollable.animate({scrollTop: getPosition()[0]}, scrollSpeed,scrollEffect);
   $scrollable.animate({scrollLeft:  getPosition()[1]}, scrollSpeed,scrollEffect);
}else{
   $scrollable.animate({scrollTop: getPosition()[0],scrollLeft:getPosition()[1]},     scrollSpeed,scrollEffect);
}
```

When i'm on a mobile version, the scrollLeft and scrollTop wont work simultaneously. So i set them apart and this seems to work in android but not on Ipad devices(IOS). So in the above example, he will do scrollLeft but not scrollTop (on ipad). Separately they work perfectly. So my question is :

How do i let the ipad do both animations?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that webkit can only scroll the $("html") element on some webkit builds, be warned as this is only the case on some versions of the webkit client.
try:

```
$("html").animate({scrollLeft:100})
```

instead of

```
$("body")
```

I can't find a lot of documentation about this but this broke a website I made a while ago and found that this solution worked if I sniffed for webkit and applied scroll animation to html instead of the body....

hope it helps

Comment: For those testing in iOS Simulator, I would add that similar jQuery to this would not work in the simulator, but worked fine on the actual device (iPhone 6, iOS 9.3.5).

Answer (score 0):

i've experience the same problem when i've developed my plugin (http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/).

There's apparently a bug in ios browser, when you animate scrollTop/scrollLeft simultanously on the body/html (specially on a absolute position), instead try to animate a specific container.

Comment: can confirm, seperately animating scrollTop or scrollLeft on the body element works fine on ios here, and together they look awfull - the screens sputters and shakes, and nothing moves.  Just wondering if $scrollable in the question actually is the `body` element.